# validate input field in jsf datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have input field in jsf datatable which i am validating and adding error message but error message doesn't get displayed. What is the best approach in validating input field in jsf datatable and adding message.

```
<h:inputTextarea id="textarea1" styleClass="inputTextarea" value="#{varreviewList.comment}">
 <f:attribute name="msgRef" value="Valid comment is Required."/>
</h:inputTextarea>
<h:message  styleClass="message" for="textarea1" id="textarea1Msg"></h:message>
```

Any help is great.

Thanks,
Sujit

Answer (score 3):

The code as far looks fine, assuming they're both placed inside a `<h:column>` (not necessarily the *same* column though), so the problem lies somewhere else.

If you after all just want to validate if the value is filled or not, then you just need to add `required="true"` to the component in question.

```
<h:inputSomething required="true" />
```

If you want to override the default required message, either use `requiredMessage` attribute (since JSF 1.2 only)

```
<h:inputSomething required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter value!" />
```

...or supply a custom `messages.properties` in the `application`'s `message-bundle` in `faces-config.xml` with the following line

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = Please enter {0}.
```

...where `{0}` is controllable by (since JSF 1.2 only, else it's the `clientId`).

```
<h:inputSomething label="This field" />
```

---

Or if you after all want a custom validator, then you need to implement [`javax.faces.validator.Validator`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html), register it as `validator` in `faces-config.xml`

```
<validator>
    <validator-id>myValidator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>com.example.MyValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

...and attach it to the input component by `validator` attribute

```
<h:inputSomething validator="myValidator" />
```

... or [`f:validator`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/f/validator.html) facet (so that you can attach multiple validators to one component)

```
<h:inputSomething>
    <f:validator validatorId="myValidator" />
</h:inputSomething>
```

Inside the implemented `validate()` method, just [`throw ValidatorException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException.html) with the desired [`FacesMessage`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) whenever needed.

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value does not match some condition) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Please enter valid value"));
    }
}
```

It will then automatically show up in the associated message component.

Comment: Hi BalusC, Thanks for the Reply i wrote custom validator but my validator is not getting invoked. When i click command button it goes into action. Nothing is required field in my page. I need check validation on some condition. I registered validator in faces config and specied in jsf page something like this. 
<h:inputSomething> 
<f:validator validatorId="myValidator" /> 
</h:inputSomething>

Comment: The attached validator will **only** be invoked when the value is **not** null or empty. For that part you normally use the `required` attribute. You may need to elaborate more about the exact functional requirement so that we can give better suited answers. Maybe you want to validate on a certain condition/dependency?

Comment: Thanks again i got validator working. 

My requirement is i have to check for dependency and display error message in datatable  row. I am able to add error message and show messages globally but not in a datatable row.

Example: if a row 5 COMMENT is required than i have to show error message in row5 column3(comment goes in column3) of datatable.

Comment: I already have <h:message> but message doesn't get displayed.

<h:inputTextarea id="textarea1" styleClass="inputTextarea" value="#{varreviewList.comment}"> 
 <f:attribute name="msgRef" value="Valid comment is Required."/> 
</h:inputTextarea> 
<h:message  styleClass="message" for="textarea1" id="textarea1Msg"></h:message>

Comment: Thanks BalusC for you responses but it looks like to me that inside datatable h:message association with inputfields is not working properly. I tried using Custom validator and server side validation. I am adding messages correctly but when it renders the message is not getting displayed. 

Thanks again for comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me inside a datatable:

```
    <ice:inputText id="inputTextt" field="#{bean[fieldValue]}" required="true"/>
<ice:message for="inputTextt"></ice:message>
```